# How many words are lmmatized?

Tags: python, nlp, lemmatization

In a data frame with 1000 texts, after doing preprocessing lemmatization, how can I find out how many words have been lemmatized in each text?

Comment: What is the validation accuracy after 10 epochs?

Comment: validation accuracy: 49.6

Comment: Your model is clearly overfitting, try adjusting the dropout values.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you run your model for just 3 epochs? I would suggest you to run it for about 20 epochs, and then see if the validation accuracy is not reducing. And the thing, I can tell you is that You need to change your this line of code:

```
    model.add(Embedding(300000,60,input_length=300))
```

To this:

```
   model.add(Embedding(k, 60,input_length=300))
```

Where you can set k as 256 or 512 or a number close to them. But 300000 would be just too much. By that, your network would focus more on the embedding layer, when the main job is of encoder and decoder.

Another thing, you should increase your LSTM units (maybe to a number like 128 or 256) in both encoder and decoder, and remove the recurrent_dropout parameter (since, you are dropping out using the dropout layer after encoder). If that still doesn't help then you can even add Batch Normalization layers to your model.